# How to filter or select information from a list of multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to filter or select information for multiple dataframes in a list of dataframes in python. First, I am saving the information from multiple excel files into a list object, taking the names of the excel files from a pre-loaded list,  such as:

```
f_list = info.f_names.dropna()
```

Then I create the list object as:

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(g) for g in f_list]
```

Then, What I am trying to do is to filter (intersect or select the information) by two ways: by columns and by rows. The reason for these is because every columns (of every excel file) is a variables and every row is peace of information of each variable (which is not necesarily realted with every columns). I am trying to select (intersect or filter) the information from pre-loaded columns_names and rows_information, such as:

```
col_names = info["Columns Names"].dropna

row_data = info["data"].dropna
```

The way I am trying to select or filter is:

```
filter_1 = dfs[dfs.columns.intersection(col_names)]

filter_2 = dfs[dfs.rows.intersection(row_data)]
```

However, it produce an error.

I would like to know if someone might help me with this or guide me towards the funtion or the command I am missing.

Comment: Hi, what is the error message?

Comment: The error message is: 'list' object has no attributes 'columns'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to filter columns and rows on the list of dataframes (dfs), not the dataframes themselves (dfs[0] for instance).
Try like this:

```py
filtered_dfs = [df.columns.intersection(col_names) for df in dfs]

filtered_dfs = [df.rows.intersection(row_data) for df in dfs]
```

Then, you can inspect a particular dataframe, like `dfiltered_dfs[idx]` (where idx is the index of the daframe in the list).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The lines of code intersect. Don't grab all the information below the column name, it just found the column names.